# Selecting nth value based on set of cells Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of ID's to compare to a SDE, and I would like to pull multiple rows from the SDE using the ID's as a reference. The reason I want to lookup nth instances is because I have multiple columns in which each column will pull a different instance so all the data can be store horizontally instead of vertically. There will be more ID's but the two on there are just for testing purposes.

The current function I have is `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C4:C="",,INDEX(SDE_materials_mat,SMALL(IF(C4:C=SDE_materials_id,ROW(SDE_materials_mat)),1))))`

That function displays the following alarm:

`Array arguments to EQ are of different size.`

Here is a copy of the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uPgFYKjfkcLfBTAcuPL__gDYeCmn1Nwu473CFMepaUk/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help, it's very appreciated!

Comment: can you provide expected output?

Comment: If you go into SDE_invtypematerials sheet and ctrl-F search for the item id's, look for the matching numbers from the typeid column to match with the Item ID column in the bp_pull sheet. I'm away from the pc atm but I can manually input the numbers if needbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C4:C, SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(
 {SDE_invTypeMaterials!B2:B&"¤"&SDE_invTypeMaterials!C2:C, SDE_invTypeMaterials!A2:A&"×"}, 
 REGEXMATCH(SDE_invTypeMaterials!A2:A&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C4:C)), 
 COUNTIFS(SDE_invTypeMaterials!A2:A, SDE_invTypeMaterials!A2:A, 
 ROW(SDE_invTypeMaterials!A2:A), "<="&ROW(SDE_invTypeMaterials!A2:A))<7), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×"), 2, 0)), "¤ ", 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: You madman, you did it! If there ends up being more than 6 materials will it automatically load the 7th or 8th row or would the function need to be updated? Thank you very much for your time and expertise!

Comment: @MichaelJetzer for 7th change `<7` to `<8` in formula. for 8th change it to `<9` etc